# Modify keyboard layout/settings to accommodate jelly comb ultra slim

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I recently purchased the [Jelly Comb Ultra Slim](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NOE7412), so far it works very well with Windows 10, however, I currently run Ubuntu 16.04 as my main OS.

So I've tried a few tests and checked a few settings but I've been unable to determine how I'm supposed to fix this. I did find this **[link](http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/Keystrokes-sending-digit-prefixes-td409334.html)**. As far as I can understand it, it says that this keyboard is imitating the way Windows keyboards work therefore it shouldn't work with Linux, and it doesn't. Side note: most of the keys don't seem to be sending any form of input in, as far as I can tell.

So my questions are: How can I make this bluetooth keyboard work, and how can I make sure I don't have to tweak any settings the next time I connect my keyboard.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: Any information at all is helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved:

This kind of bluetooth keyboard has a special functionality that is activated when NUM-LOCK is on (it's pretty useless). If you turn off NUM-LOCK the keyboard works as expected.

So if you're having this problem just turn off NUM-LOCK.

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu 18 there was no gui for this, I installed `apt install numlockx` and ran `numlockx off` to disable it's strange preference for numlock defaulting to on.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote - it might not have helped you mr downvoter - does not mean it is wrong as it 100% was needed for me to get this to work.